# add new SSH user account for AZURE ubuntu VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

I have an azure ubuntu vm up and running (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS) to learn and experiment.  Thus far my NGINX / NODE.js / Socket.io experiments all worked great, but in my effort to see if there was a way to EXPORT an Azure VM and import it locally, I created a headache for myself.

I came across this resource [Download a Linux VHD from Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/download-vhd), and without reading close enough (in hindsight) I ran the following commands via an SSH session from my mac book pro:

```
ssh azureuser@<publicIpAddress>
sudo waagent -deprovision+user -force
exit
```

So now, needless to say, I am unable to login to the VM using ssh.  I AM still able to access the account via the Azure portal though, and Im fairly certain theres a way to re-create my user account that I can use to access the machine via SSH.

Anyone familiar with how / where in the Azure portal I would accomplish this?

Now when I try to connect via SSH as the previous user, I get "Host key verification failed".  Will I need to just scrap this VM altogether?

When I try to access the Serial Console for the VM, I just get this repeating over and over:  "WARNING cloud-init does not appear to be running"

Comment: You can attach the OS disk as a data disk to another Azure VM and configure the user file in the disk. Then you can create a vm with the OS disk.

Answer (score 0):

Because the command you ran generalized OS, no user information.

You can try copying disk/vhd, make image of copy disk/vhd and try new deployment using image.

Hope this helps.